# AppHarbor ServiceStack.Razor v4 Could not load file or assembly 'xxx'

Tags: appharbor, servicestack-razor

I am trying to Host a ServiceStack Razor website on AppHarbor. the website builds but when I navigate to the site i get the following Error

> Could not load file or assembly 'CfpPortal' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

The stack track is as follows

> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'CfpPortal' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
>      System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'CfpPortal' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'CfpPortal' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

My web.Config file is the following

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.90.0" newVersion="1.0.90.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="ServiceStack" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
        <add namespace="CfpPortal" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Fixed this issue it was because on a solution level i had set everything to build for Any CPU, but on the project level I had a project that was building for x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue it was because on a solution level i had set everything to build for Any CPU, but on the project level I had a project that was building for x64.